# [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "xxx". Expected Number with value X, got String with value "X"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

**`App.vue`**

```
<v-text-field v-model="daysNumber" type="number"></v-text-field>

<MyComponent :daysNumber="daysNumber"/>

  data: () => ({
    daysNumber: 5,
```

**`MyComponent.vue`**

```
props: {
    daysNumber: { type: Number, required: true }
  },
```

All works great until I increase the number un in the numeric textbox: (from initial '5' to '6'):
Error:

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "daysNumber".
>   Expected Number with value 6, got String with value "6".
>
> found in
>
> ```
> ---> <MyComponent> at src/components/MyComponent.vue
>        <VContent>
>          <VApp>
>            <App> at src/App.vue
>              <Root>
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the [.number](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number) modifier to `v-model`, otherwise the type from the input will be string.

```
<v-text-field v-model.number="daysNumber" type="number"></v-text-field>
```

Comment: can't be this thing inferred from the "type"? seems strange to repeat the same twice

Comment: There are 2 different things. v-model is a general way of passing data, pretty much agnostic of the HTML tags you're using, it actually works very well on components. for v-model to be aware of type it should make assumptions regarding the semantics of a field named type on any component and that's not a good idea. Think about it this way, you could use a component that has a field type, but it uses it for showing a list of groceries, in this case type="number" doesn't mean the same thing.

Comment: myntzanim neavoastri

Comment: A life was saved today. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is a `.number` modifier in Vue that transforms the `v-model` in a number, so you could use:

```
<v-text-field v-model.number="daysNumber" type="number"></v-text-field>
```

Reference:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number

Answer (score -1):

For others that may come across this, my issue was different. Adding .number to v-model caused the same error.

My ID field was wrong.
It was using the field name

```
:id="dataModel.fieldname"
```

Instead of the correct index

```
:id="dataModel.index"
```